# How to convert nest json attributes to dataframe on spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert json string to dataframe on spark, and below is my code

```
val payload = """{"invoice":[{"currency_code":"USD", "customer_detail":{"partner_name":"name","bill_to_city":"Arlington","bill_to_state":"Texas","bill_to_country":"US","contact_phone":"123.456.7890","country_name":"United States"}}]}]}"""


val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
    .json(Seq(payload).toDS())
    .selectExpr("explode(invoice) as invoice")
    .select("invoice.*")

df.show(false) // Show contents of DataFrame
```

But in the result, those nest attributes, like partner_name, bill_to_city etc doesn't show, only customer_detail shows, how to fix the code to make the dataframe show every attributes?

[image: schema]

This is my schema

```
root
 |-- currency_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- customer_detail: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bill_to_city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bill_to_country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bill_to_state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contact_phone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- partner_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer_detail column is of type struct, you can convert a struct to fields column using ".*" at the end of the column:

```
df.select("currency_code", "customer_detail.*").show(false)

+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|currency_code|bill_to_city|bill_to_country|bill_to_state|contact_phone|country_name |partner_name|
+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|USD          |Arlington   |US             |Texas        |123.456.7890 |United States|name        |
+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have a column of type array of struct then you need to explode that column first:

```
df.select(col("currency_code"), explode(col("customer_detail")).as("customer_detail"))
  .select("currency_code", "customer_detail.*").show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and what if I have an array of struct, how to do that?